# Solve $r=(p-1)+pr_1+p^2r_2$ for $r_1$ and $r_2$ when $r(p-1) \equiv 1$ (mod $p^3$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be an odd prime. $\mathbb Z_{p^3}=\left\{0,1,...,p^3-1\right\}$

1) Let $r$ be an element of $\mathbb Z_{p^3}$. Then, we can define $r$ as follows:
$r=(p-1)+pr_1+p^2r_2$ for some $0\leq r_1\leq p-1$, and $0\leq r_2 \leq p-1 $. Assume we have $r(p-1) \equiv 1$ (mod $p^3$). Then, what is $r_1$ and $r_2$ in terms of $p$?

2)Can we find a general form for $r \in \mathbb Z_{p^k}$ when $r(p-1)\equiv 1$ (mod $p^{k-1}$)? That is can we find $r_1$, $r_2$,...$r_{k-1}$ for $r=(p-1)+pr_1+p^2r_2+\cdots+p^{k-1}r_{k-1}$ where $0 \leq r_i\leq p-1$ and $r(p-1)\equiv 1$ (mod $p^{k-1}$)

Comment: Maybe lift one step at a time, deal with mod $p^2$ before going to $p^3$.

Comment: Actually, for $r \in \mathbb Z_{p}$ $r\equiv p-1 $ (mod $p$) and  for $r \in \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ $r\equiv (p-1)+p(p-2) $ (mod $p^2$). However, for this case $r \neq (p-1)+p(p-2)+p(p-3)$ as we would  expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It looks as if we are trying to find the inverse of $p-1$ modulo $p^3$. Maybe the inverse of $1-p$ would be more familiar as $1+p+p^2+\cdots$.

So changing sign and cutting off at $p^2$ we get $-1-p-p^2$. If we want a $p-1$ in front, change to $(p-1)-2p-p^2$.